# "Unable to find config file..." when trying to run a simple java class on Tomcat/Axis

Tags: java, tomcat, applet, axis

The error I receive in the server window upon trying to access the Java class is:

```
Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB- 
INF/server-config.wsdd
```

The error I receive in the browser window is:

```
No service is available at this URL
```

Running Tomcat 8.5.34 and Axis 1.4 on Windows 10.

I have added Environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
AXISCLASSPATH = C:\axis\lib
```

The URL of the java class is:

```
http://localhost:8080/axis/HelloWorld.jws
```

and the location of the java file is:

```
C:\axis\HelloWorld.jws
```

The contents of the java class are:

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.